# LinqResult.Any() Resulting In NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, linq, any

What could be causing this error:

NullReferenceException was unhanded, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
var LinqResult = 
from a in Db.Table
select new {Table = a};

if(LinqResult.Any())
{
    //Blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: My guess would be 'Db' is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that either Db or Db.Table has not yet been instantiated at the point of execution of that query. Can you post any additional code for context?

Comment: Probably. @Soo can test that, anything on LinqResult will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely either `Db` or `Db.Table` are `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably that Db is null. The exception happens when you do the .Any(), but this is because of defered execution.

Comment: If Db was `null` then it would throw the exception on the query line.

Answer (score 0):

The `Db.Table` value is `null`.

It is not `Db` being `null` as other people have suggested.  Else the exception would have occured on the actual query.